# Which Windows Mobile emulator is the best?

Tags: html, emulation, windows-phone-7-emulator

I have Windows 7 system. I need a free downloadable Windows Mobile emulator for testing my mobile webpages. I have downloaded and tried to use Cellular Emulator, which is asking for Visual Studio. Can you recommend a user-friendly Windows Mobile (version 7) emulator which does not require Visual Studio? If so, please provide the link. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can test everything on several Lumia Devices:

- [Remote Device Access for Nokia Lumia](http://developer.nokia.com/resources/library/Lumia/remote-device-access-for-nokia-lumia.html#toc_Installingyoursoftware)
- Some devices you can access:[image: Some devices from Remote Device Access for Nokia Lumia]

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft themselves provide the best emulator (which I used extensively). It is much better than any open third-party emulator.

Link: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53424

Note: you need to use a Windows 8 machine.